# How to add multiple routes in angular 9

Tags: angular9

I have a project on angular 9. where i want execute **Three** components in my homepage named `header`, `body`, and `footer`. and i have other two componets `login` and `signup`. These are working fine but homepage components are not working. Only `header` component is loading, others are not. I have found similar questions but they are not solving my problem

**what i have tried**

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './component/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './component/signup/signup.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './component/header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './component/body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './component/footer/footer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '' , redirectTo: 'header,body,footer', pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'header', component:HeaderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'body' , component:BodyComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'footer', component:FooterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login', component:LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signup' , component:SignupComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

you need to create one common component called home component and include header,body,footer into that

home.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

route

```
{
   path: 'home', component:HomeComponent
},
{
    path: '' , redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
},
```